# Will the entire query fail when trying to insert a duplicate key?

Tags: mysql

If I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO map
    SELECT 5, product_id FROM products WHERE price < 500 )
```

Say this tries to insert 300 rows into the map table. Say 20 of the inserts generate duplicate key errors. Will the other 280 rows be inserted or will the entire query fail?

If so, what is the best way to write this query so that the non-duplicate rows are inserted and the duplicates are ignored?

Comment: you can create a procedure or a script (php, pyhton etc) to execute this sql command and verify after insert the number of rows inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query will fail at first duplicate key. If you want to continue inserting next use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO map (map_id, product_id)
SELECT  5, product_id FROM products WHERE price < 500
```

When inserting multiple rows like this, do not put the query into `VALUES()`.